# Execution-time address binding, logical addresses creation

Tags: operating-systems

In the operating systems that make use of the execution-time address binding who is responsible for the creation of logical addresses?

EDIT

I'm thinking that the logical addresses are generated by the compiler and are included in the relocatable code

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: What is the context where you encountered this?  What research have you done?  What do you mean by "execution-time address binding"?  What do you mean by "creation of logical addresses"?